# What would cause my dataset to drop a row?

Tags: vb.net

I have a SQL statement that, when ran in SSMS, returns 6 rows. After attaching the statement to the command text of a VB.NET SQLCommand with a command type of Text, reading it with a SqlDataReader, and attaching it to a dataset, the returned dataset only has 5 rows.

At first, I assumed it was an issue with the data. However, after several bouts of removing and adding rows to the source table with varying data, it was obvious that I was always getting the total row count - 1. I then decided to just use a SQLDataAdapter to populate the DataSet and the proper number of rows was returned.

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim sqlCmd as New SqlCommand
Dim sqlCn As New SqlConnection
Dim sqlR As New SqlCommand

sqlCn.ConnectionString = "SomeConnectionString"

With sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from DummyTable"
           .CommandType = CommandType.Text
           .Connection  = sqlCn
End With

sqlCn.Open()
sqlR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
sqlR.Read()

If sqlR.HasRows() Then
    ds.Tables.Add("DummyTable")
    ds.Tables(0).Load(sqlR)
    return ds
End If
```

From here, I'm expecting to see the 6 rows from DummyTable. Instead, I'm seeing only 5.

However, if I use the following:

```
Dim da as SqlDataAdapter
Using sqlCn
    da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlCmd.CommandText, sqlCn)
    da.Fill(ds)
End Using
Return ds
```

I get the full 6 rows. Is there something I'm missing about the way a DataSet's Tables.Add(tableName) or Tables(n).Load(dataReader) works? I had never worked with SqlDataReaders prior to this and was told to stick with them as our other projects use them.

Comment: I suspect that the line sqlR.Read() is the culprit, it already advances the reader for one row. Remove it and try again.

Comment: @Esko Well, I feel like a fool for not even recognizing that. That fixed the issue! Wow. Resolved within 3 minutes. I'm going to go run through the rest of the project and see if this instruction I was given by our senior devs is repeated anywhere else, causing problems. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already reading the first line of the query with the line sqlR.Read(). This line is unnecessary in your code. Remove it and it will work fine.

Also SqlCommand, SqlConnection and SqlDataReader implement iDisposable, so be sure to use using-statement with them:

```
Using sqlCn As New SqlConnection("SomeConnectionString")
  sqlCn.Open()
  Using sqlCmd as New SqlCommand
       With sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from DummyTable"
           .CommandType = CommandType.Text
           .Connection  = sqlCn
       End With

       Using sqlR As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
          If sqlR.HasRows() Then
             Dim ds As New DataSet 
             ds.Tables.Add("DummyTable")
             ds.Tables(0).Load(sqlR)
             return ds
          End If
       End Using
  End Using
End Using
```